# Restore Magento 2 attribute and related products

Tags: magento2, attributes, related-products

I have accidentally deleted the attribute set from the store and due to this the products also deleted from my multistore shops. by just pressing this 
[image]
I have found an extension in GitHub trashcan but it says it will not restore the already deleted products.

also, I have not database backup so please any suggestion how I can restore the products with the same attribute?

My Magento version is 2.2.0

Comment: Restore  database.

Comment: @SouravI have not database backup sir

Comment: ask hosting company they restore

Comment: You donot have any option if you donot have any database backup

Comment: @AmitBera I want to know if the attribute is deleted the products also will be deleted related to the attribute actually I have not deleted products I have deleted the attribute only. some products showing but some is not

Comment: As per as,your screenshot you have delete `attribute set` not attribute

Comment: yea but due to products will also be going to delete? if I restore attribute set then it will work again or not?

Answer (score 0):

the relation between your tables products and attributes was deleted, the solution is simple, restore your DB to previous snapshot